# Deploy a maven site into Alfresco through FTP

Tags: maven, maven-2, ftp, alfresco

I'm experiencing some issues at the moment, when deploying maven site into Alfresco.

In my company, we use Alfresco as ECM, in our forge.
Since this tool supports FTP, and index all content of any kind of text document, I'd like to push my maven site into.

But even I'm able to deploy site manually through FTP on Alfresco, or upload it automatically using maven, I'm not able to combine both :

Here my part pom.xml

```
<distributionManagement>
    [...]
    <site>
        <id>forge-alfresco</id>
        <name>Serveur Alfresco de la Forge</name>
        <url>ftp://alfresco.mycompany.corp/Alfresco/doc/site</url>
    </site>
</distributionManagement>

<build>
    <extensions>
        <!-- Enabling the use of FTP -->
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
</build>
```

And here, part of my settings.xml

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>forge-alfresco</id>
        <username>jrrevy</username>
        <password>xxxxxxxx</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

When I try to deploy using site:deploy, I facing to this : 
    [INFO] [site:deploy {execution: default-cli}]
    Reply received: 220 FTP server ready

```
Command sent: USER jrrevy

Reply received: 331 User name okay, need password for jrrevy

Command sent: PASS xxxxxx

Reply received: 230 User logged in, proceed

Command sent: SYST

Reply received: 215 UNIX Type: Java FTP Server

Remote system is UNIX Type: Java FTP Server
Command sent: TYPE I

Reply received: 200 Command OK

ftp://alfresco.mycompany.corp/Alfresco/doc/site/ - Session: Opened  
[INFO] Pushing D:\project\workspaces\yyyyy\myproject\target\site
[INFO]    >>> to ftp://alfresco.mycompany.corp/Alfresco/doc/site/./
Command sent: CWD /Alfresco/doc/site/

Reply received: 250 Requested file action OK

Recursively uploading directory D:\project\workspaces\yyyyy\myproject\target\site as ./
processing = D:\project\workspaces\yyyyy\myproject\target\site as ./
Command sent: CWD ./

Reply received: 550 Invalid path ./

Command sent: MKD ./

Reply received: 250 /Alfresco/doc/site/.

Command sent: CWD ./

Reply received: 550 Invalid path ./

ftp://alfresco.mycompany.corp/Alfresco/doc/site/ - Session: Disconnecting  
ftp://alfresco.mycompany.corp/Alfresco/doc/site/ - Session: Disconnected
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error uploading site

Embedded error: Unable to change cwd on ftp server to ./ when processing D:\project\workspaces\yyyyy\myproject\target\site
```

I can't figure out what the problem. Maybe the plugin version is not compatible... Maybe Alfresco's implementation is not full compatible (forgive me for this outrage ;)), maybe there is a configuration in the server properties I missed.

I don't really know where to look for, and after some time googlin', I can't find what the matter.

I have already some workarounds. I'll try to upload the website using webdav protocol, and I can use some extra features (like deploy artifatcts of Jenkins) on our CI plateform, but I really want to know what's the problem.

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it looks like an Alfresco issue : issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-4724.
I'm running under Alfresco 3.1, and this issue seems to be solved in 3.3.5 and above.

Comment: Wow, Alfresco 3.1 is old... There have been rather a large number of bug fixes since then, it's probably worth upgrading!

Comment: Yes I know :). My own company in an Alfresco Gold partner integrator. I'm currently developping on Alfresco 4.0.1, but our software factory was satted up a few years ago. It evolved there is a efw weeks, and i'll try again my work. As far as I tested, it seems to work :)

Comment: If you're not going live for a few weeks, you might even be able to go straight to 4.0.2 (due out soon)